# All possible permutations of dictionaries combinations out of 2 lists

Tags: python, dictionary, permutation

Suppose I have 2 lists in python :

```
keys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

values = [7, 8, 9]
```

I want to get all permutations out of those 2 lists

something like:

```
d = [{1:7, 2:8, 3:9}, {1:8, 2:9, 3:7}, ....... ]
```

How could I achieve that?

Comment: how do you want the results presented? What is the criteria for the dictionary `d`?

Comment: Why do you want a list of dictionaries?

Comment: Thanks all, DSM gave me the answer I wanted

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
>>> import itertools
>>> keys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> values = [7, 8, 9]
>>> d = [dict(zip(kperm, values)) for kperm in itertools.permutations(keys, len(values))]
>>> len(d)
120
>>> d[:10]
[{1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 9}, {1: 7, 2: 8, 4: 9}, {1: 7, 2: 8, 5: 9}, {1: 7, 2: 8, 6: 9}, {1: 7, 2: 9, 3: 8}, {1: 7, 3: 8, 4: 9}, {1: 7, 3: 8, 5: 9}, {1: 7, 3: 8, 6: 9}, {1: 7, 2: 9, 4: 8}, {1: 7, 3: 9, 4: 8}]
```

Comment: Karl, I was exercising the substitution ciphers and I was trying to decrypt a simple cipher myself, to see how far I can go
The keys represent the most frequent characters in English
The values are the most frequent characters in the cipher text
The decrypt function that I was implementing, takes a key represented by dictionary.
So I was trying to get all possible dictionaries, where keys are most frequent characters and values are most frequent characters in cipher.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>>import itertools
>>>list(itertools.product(*[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]]))
>>>[(1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9)]
```

Comment: for list of dicts, you can do `[{k: v} for k, v in itertools.product(*[keys, values])]` but I really don't see the point of dictionary here...

Comment: You can just apply dict to any iterable of pairs.